# Как вызвать функцию php в html

Tags: php

Как можно сделать так, чтобы функция check_domen() вызывалась только после того, как мы передали в $_POST имя домена, который необходимо проверить?

```
<?php
function check_domen()
{
    $host = $_POST;
    $json = file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/json/' . $host . '?lang=ru');
    $array = json_decode($json, TRUE);

    if (strcasecmp($array['status'], 'fail') == 0)
        echo "Домен свободен";
    else
        echo "Домен зарегестрирован";

}

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="введите Домен">
    <input type="submit" value="отправить">
</form>
<?php check_domen() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Что это за функция такая, и что Вам нужно конкретно? Выложите код, без кода ничем не помочь.

Comment: Прошу прощения, забыл вставить код...

Comment: Нельзя в код добавлять то, что было в ответе. Это сбивает с толку. Если есть новый вопрос или уточнение к ответу - надо и спрашивать, а не править вопрос не своим решением

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо проверять отправлена ли форма и есть ли там имя

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['name']) && !empty(trim($_POST['name']))) {
    check_domen();
}

?>
```

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали, и теперь функция всегда выдает Домен свободен, с чем это связано?

Comment: @Rumeone Значит некорректное имя вводите. Смотрите отладкой что происходит внутри функции.  Потому что при наличии домена - всё так и выведет: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/086b4db8aba1c6da5362518a8018b65d83923052   (это ответ на http://ip-api.com/json/pinterest.ru?lang=ru)

Comment: @Rumeone Также замечу, что должно быть так: `$host = $_POST['name'];`. Вы же имя должны как-то получить из поста?