# Почему функция всегда выдает один и тот же ответ?

Tags: php

Написал функцию, которая проверяет занятость домена. Если вызывать без кода html, то работает верно, а так только ответ Домен свободен выдает и все в чем причина?

```
<?php
function check_domen()
{
    $host = $_POST;
    $json = file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/json/' . $host . '?lang=ru');
    $array = json_decode($json, TRUE);

    if (strcasecmp($array['status'], 'fail') == 0)
        echo "Домен свободен";
    else
        echo "Домен зарегестрирован";

}

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="введите Домен">
    <input type="submit" value="отправить">
</form>
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['name']) && !empty(trim($_POST['name']))) {
    check_domen();
}
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну как минимум строка `$host = $_POST;` делает явно не то, что вы хотели сделать

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вызвать функцию php в html](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1280401/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-php-%d0%b2-html)

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь отправить запрос со всем массивом $_POST.
Вам стоит вместо `$host = $_POST;` написать `$host = $_POST['name'];`.

Comment: Изменил как вы сказали. Но теперь выдает такую ошибку(добавил фотографию в вопрос). Все так же выдает что домен зарегистрирован, но если запускать код без html, то не зарегистрирован(что является верным)

Comment: @Rumeone ну кому вы заливаете, у вас там пробел чётко виден

Comment: @Rumeone Вы допустили пробел в конце домена. Можете написать `$host = trim($_POST['name']);`, чтобы удалить пробелы при проверке домена